# Where should AWS EC2 Key Pair be stored?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Please can you suggest safe places to store the key pairs that are associated with EC2 instances?

Is it safe to store these kinds of things within Amazon's S3 storage if they are restricted to your account?

I currently have it on my PC... at home.  Is that bad?

Comment: That depends. If you're a bank, that's probably horribly bad. If it's for your blog, it's probably fine. S3 might be a good idea, might be a bad idea if you've got the permissions mixed up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to protect your EC2 keypairs, which are just SSH keys, is to encrypt them with a passphrase (and follow your normal password management process for that passphrase).  Assuming you are using linux, you can use `ssh-keygen -p -f $file` to encrypt the key.  You should keep a backup, preferably physically secured (i.e. a thumb drive in a safety deposit box or something).  I am assuming you are talking about the private half of the key, since the public key is obviously public.

Theoretically, it would be better to store the key on a TPM on your workstation, or on a smartcard, but there are usually practical problems with this solution when dealing with SSH keys.

Whether it is bad to store the key on your home PC depends on whether this is a violation of policy.  If it's not, honestly, there is little reason to view this as being any worse than storing it on a laptop you use for work.

You can certainly keep a backup of the key in S3 (instead of a physical backup).  The threat model is such that you are already having a very bad day (in terms of data leaks and interruption of service, among other things) if someone is able to access your AWS account.  But, unless there is some security principal who might have access to the S3 bucket with your key but not be allowed to log into the machines, you would need to find another way.  If you store a copy in S3, at least make sure it is encrypted with a passphrase.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the public key can be stored wherever you'd like. Tattoo it on your forehead, for instance. :)

The private key is what you need to protect, as it is truly your identity. Anyone that gets their hands on your (unencrypted) key can have their way with your servers. So, protect it and back it up as you would any other important but confidential file. Encrypt it and save it on a flash drive, print it out on paper and store it in a safe as a last resort, etc. If you want to store it in S3, that's probably fine, but I'd only do that in its encrypted form.

Comment: That's one long tattoo.

Comment: @Coulton EEAA's idea is not that bad. Tattoo it as a QR code on your forehead then have something that authenticates you to your instances when you face your webcam.

Comment: Bummer when you need to rotate your key, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could also utilize AWS secrets Manager to store and rotate private ssh keys.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-secrets-manager-securely-store-rotate-ssh-key-pairs/

https://medium.com/@nilouferbustani/securing-ssh-private-keys-using-aws-secrets-manager-6d93537c1037

Answer (score -1):

EC2 key pair is need to access the EC2 server for very first access. Once you have access the Server through Keypair then need to change with Strong password. This is right way to access the EC2 Server. Kindly correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: The key pair allows you to get the password by decrypting it. It is secured by the key pair.

Comment: @Luke Then why they mentioned like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496347/unable-to-get-password-for-the-instance-created-from-ami

Comment: Given that when you're using a linux instance the SSH key basically is the password it makes no sense to me to change it. I could be wrong though.